# Can an ASPX file in Azure blob storage be utilized by an Azure function in any way?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, static-site

Can an Azure Function using .net core references read and utilize an aspx file located in Azure Blob storage?

Comment: You can definitively read files from Blob storage, but running code dynamically?  Not sure. Can you explain your use case and why you're trying to run code like that?

Comment: This link shows how to utilize .net core from Azure functions. I’m curious how far this can be taken in a serverless manner.  https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=web&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwiVh83frJvjAhVVUs0KHctjDPAQzPwBCAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Freynders.co%2Fmove-asp-net-core-to-azure-functions-in-4-steps%2F&psig=AOvVaw11cgjRm9S8nCgRWIjCSnyH&ust=1562332636324776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe could get it to serve the client-side HTML, CSS, and Javascript, but it won't be able to understand the server-side code. If you are only going to include client-side code, there there is little reason to use an aspx file.

The primary reason is because .Net Core and the .Net Framework aren't cross-compatible.  In the case of websites there is an additional problem. .Net Framework is tightly integrated with IIS, and .Net Core uses [Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Inside a .Net Core functions container IIS isn't a dependency, so there is no guarantee it will be available to you even if you can overcome the Framework/Core barrier (likely it will not be there).

There are a couple ways to do something similar:

1. Use Functions to [build an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-serverless-api). They can certainly serve static files from Blob storage like HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Implement any server-side code you were planning as Functions. This is the recommended way to host a website using Functions.
2. Use a Web App to serve your aspx pages. Keep in mind that if your plan is to load the files dynamically, Web Forms [doesn't interpret](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306575/how-to-dynamically-include-files-in-asp-net) server-side code on the fly either.
3. Use [Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) to create .Net Core pages that are similar in structure to Web Forms and host them in Web App. [It is possible](http://www.luckenuik.net/hosting-your-aspnet-core-razor-pages-inside-azure-functions/) to host a Razor Pages site within Azure Functions, but I would not recommend it.